# running SKYPE4COM on iis 64bit

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config, skype, skype4com

I create a web application that communicate with Skype by using SKYPE4COM. Now, I have finished with my coding and the program can run properly. I use VS2008 and config a debug mode that run on x86 (Actually my machine is 64 bit)

So,I put my code on iis7 and run this page but it's not working anymore.
Does anyone have a idea to fix this problem?

I search all information in the internet. Maybe the problem is SKYPE4COM must run as a 32 bit application.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. SKYPE4COM is a 32 bits COM server and so it registers itself in the 32 bits registry halve.

You can write a COM "[LOCAL SERVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693716%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)" that's simple an executable that exposes COM components. Since you have control over this LOCAL SERVER you can set it up to run as x86 and then SKYPE4COM should work (assuming the user which IIS runs have the required rights)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your web app for 32bits.
Build -> Platform Target: x86.

Answer (score 0):

Set your application pool under IIS to classic that should do the trick